# What is the advantage of using log softmax instead of softmax?

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function

Are there any advantages to using log softmax over softmax? What are the reasons to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are a number of advantages of using [log softmax over softmax](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289369/log-probabilities-in-reference-to-softmax-classifier) including practical reasons like improved numerical performance and [gradient optimization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174481/why-to-optimize-max-log-probability-instead-of-probability). These advantages can be extremely important for implementation especially when training a model can be computationally challenging and expensive. At the heart of using log-softmax over softmax is the use of [log probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability) over probabilities, which has nice information theoretic interpretations.

When used for classifiers the log-softmax has the effect of heavily penalizing the model when it fails to predict a correct class. Whether or not that penalization works well for solving your problem is open to your testing, so both log-softmax and softmax are worth using.

Answer (score 15):

Log softmax is
$$\log(\exp(x)/\sum(\exp(x)))
=x - \log(\sum(\exp(x))).$$
Now $\log(\sum(\exp(x))) \approx \max(x)$, since the sum is dominated by the largest entry.

We see that log softmax is nearly just $x-\max(x)$ which is naturally much faster to compute than anything involving logarithms and exponentials. We are also guaranteed that the output won't be of a vastly different scale than the input.

Another reason is that when softmax is used with log likelihood loss, we're gonna take the logarithm of the entries anyway.